# Thread is not stopping properly

Tags: java

I'm new to java concurrent coding and encounter an issue. The following code cannot stop while it runs. Who can tell me why? Thanks

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Test {
    private static boolean stop;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            System.out.println(stop);
            while (!stop) {
            }
        }).start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stop = true;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println(stop);
    }
}
```

I also try to run the following code and it can stop. Who can tell me why? Thanks

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
    private static boolean stop;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            System.out.println(stop);
            while (!stop) {
                System.out.println("  ");
            }
        }).start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stop = true;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println(stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: A boolean is false by default. Your boolean "stop" is therefore false. Therefore, your "while (!stop)" is equivalent to a "while(true)" -> infinite loop

Comment: Hi Chris Neve, I have changed variable "stop" to true in the code when the new thread is running. I think it can stop.

Comment: The implementation is permitted to optimize the threaded code under the assumption that no other thread is going to modify `stop` because you haven't told it otherwise. The designers of Java had two choices -- make all code run slow all the time just to be absolutely sure nothing goes wrong in the 0.1% of code that communicates between threads or require people who communicate between threads to use specific code to do so. The latter choice, the sensible one, was the one they made.

Comment: You never reach the point where you set the boolean to true. It never gets out of the loop

Comment: Declare `stop` `volatile`.

Comment: Acutally when you add a print inside the loop, it works...

Comment: @Maxouille that's not guaranteed. It would only work if the implementation of `System.out.println` is synchronized.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why ? Why does `synchronized` make it work ? I don't get it.

Comment: @Maxouille because synchronization establishes a happens-before relationship.

Comment: @Maxouille That's the only way it's guaranteed to work. But likely the reason it actually does work is because the implementation's optimizer can't tell whether or not `println` could or does modify `stop` somehow because it doesn't look that deeply into its code. So even if it's not `synchronized`, it would probably still happen to make it work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thx ! I get it now ;) Seems logic

Answer (score 8):

Because you've not indicated to the compiler that `stop` might be changed and read by multiple threads:

```
private static boolean stop;
```

it is allowed to optimize this:

```
while (!stop) {
}
```

to

```
if (!stop) {
  while (true) {
  }
}
```

which will never stop if `stop` is initially false.

Declaring `stop` `volatile`:

```
private static volatile boolean stop;
```

disallows this optimization.

Comment: What is the rule of this optimization ? Does a to `stop` inside the loop prevent this ? Or an affectation to `false` ? Is this optimization rule documented somewhere ? (And btw, nice explanation)

Comment: The optimization is a consequence of [the memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). Simply using `stop` in the loop is not sufficient: you need to do something that establishes a happens-before relationship between the write and read of the variable: synchronization is one such thing; making the variable volatile is another.

Answer (score -3):

JVM typically optimizes your code before actually executing it. In your case, `while(!stop){}` gets optimized to `while(true){}`. This happens because you aren't explicitly accessing your static variable via synchronized function, and JVM assumes the variable won't change in Thread unsafe manner.

To avoid the optimization, place anything in your while loop. You could do something like:

```
while(!stop) {
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1); // You could also call any other function here.
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

In this case, JVM wouldn't try to optimize, and your code will execute as expected.

EDIT:
While this does work currently, but based on comments, I concur that this can change in future versions (or in other parallel implementations of JDK/JVM). Declaring the variable as `volatile` is the best way to avoid that optimization.

Comment: "To avoid the optimization, place anything in your while loop" No, this doesn't work. You have to put something in the loop which causes `stop` to be re-read; `sleep` is not something that would do that.

Comment: You'd have to do something that the optimizer can't prove won't modify `stop` or allow another thread to modify `stop`. But how can you possibly know how smart future Java optimizers will be?

Comment: Tried Thread.sleep with jdk 1.8.0_181. The stop variable was re-read and execution stopped as expected. But I agree, this is JVM implementation dependent.